# Analyse code coverage of a nodejs app during a crash recover story

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai, istanbul

I am actually trying to reach the highest score of code coverage for my nodeJS app, I am using Mocha + Chai + Istanbul to ensure this code coverage.

Part of my code's app is dedicated to recover a potential service interruption, to do so most of app objects are serialized real time in Redis.

So when the app start for the first time, I am exclusively loading data from mongoDB. After a crash recovery, I am also loading data from Redis. Obviously my app is not using the same part of the code to perform this two kind of initialization.

For this reason Istanbul dead-code report is not accurate and differ if I am running my test in the 1st or the 2nd case.

I am looking for a way to simulate a process interruption without killing Istanbul process to be able to get a complete Istanbul report.

I tried to solved it by using child_process :

```
var masterLogger = require("./storage/file-logger").master;
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
var redis_flush = exec("redis-cli -n 6 flushall");
var srv1;
var srv2;

redis_flush.on("close", function() {
    masterLogger.fatal("Redis clear");
    redis_flush = null;

    masterLogger.fatal("Starting SRV1");
    srv1 = exec("npm test");
    srv1.on("close", function() {
        masterLogger.fatal("SRV1 killed");
        srv1 = null;

        masterLogger.fatal("Starting SRV2");
        srv2 = exec("npm test");
        srv2.on("close", function() {
            masterLogger.fatal("SRV2 killed");
            srv2 = null;
        });
    });
});

process.on("SIGINT", function() {
    if (redis_flush)
        redis_flush.kill();
    else if (srv1)
        srv1.kill();
    else if (srv2)
        srv2.kill();
    else
        process.exit(0);
});
```

But Istanbul is providing a code-coverage report only for this part of code (Where I reached 100% ^^)...

NB: **npm test** -> Start my app with a **test** env

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research on this issue, I realized it was probably easier to "concatenate" the result of two distinct execution.

And apparently the Istanbul team thought about it ->
[Look at the last answer of this github ticket](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/97)

This solution gives me a way to generate multiple **coverage** files and then generate a single **report**.